# How safe is to use docker in production?

Tags: docker, automation

We are planning to make all our deplyments automated and we are planning to use jenkins with docker.But this link says https://thehftguy.com/2016/11/01/docker-in-production-an-history-of-failure/ that it has some problems in past.
So i am figuring whether is it safe to use docker in production?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Docker is no less safe than any other hosting option.

It's just a matter of understanding the potential failures of each deployment and hosting option, and accounting for those failures, learning as you run into problems.